# Delegates question - Basic

Tags: c#

Alright, I have the following code: (copied from my book).

```
class MyDelegate
{
    public delegate void Func(string s);
    public void Show(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In MyD1: " + s);
    }
}
class Test
{
    static void Show(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In test: " + s);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDelegate md = new MyDelegate();
        MyDelegate.Func f= new MyDelegate.Func(md.Show);
        MyDelegate.Func f1= new MyDelegate.Func(Show);
        f("hello");
        f1("Hello");
        f1 = f;
        f1("world");
    }
}
```

The output is: `In MyD1: hello
                In TestShow Hello
                InMyD1: world`

Now, I didn't understand why the last line of the output is in "InMyD1" .
because f1 delegate is called and not f.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also it is usually a good habit to have your code and your output synchronized. You're saying that you have `TestShow` in your output, but you do not have it in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote `f1 = f`.

Therefore, you are calling `f`.

Answer (score 0):

`f1` is being reassigned the function reference of `f`. Likewise, if you just assigned it another function in place, such as:

```
f1 = s => Console.WriteLine("Another function: " + s);
```

You'd get other output.

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = f;
```

This sets f1 to f thats why you have world instead of Hello